# Promise pending when calling a function inside a hook using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I'm using axios to pull data from an API (arr of objects) but for some reason I keep getting promise pending when calling it inside the hook.

I used promise chaining to ensure that the code executes synchronously but it's still the same.

When I for example use "console.log(selectedVideo[0]" I get "undefined". I assume it's because it's calling API before it has finished pulling the data, correct?

```
    const url = `${baseURL}videos?api_key=${apiKEY}`;

    const fetchData = axios
        .get(url)
        .then((resp) => setSelectedVideo(resp.data));

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    // sets the state for the video
    const [selectedVideo, setSelectedVideo] = useState(fetchData);

    console.log(selectedVideo);
```

Comment: try putting settimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will be executed on each component re-render, even the `fetchData` result will not be a `function`, it will be `undefined` ( the return from `setSelectedVideo` ), you need to turn `fetchData` to function.

Also, as the data come from `API` you need to set a default value for the `state` for example `null` or an `empty object`

I think what you are looking for is.

```
    const url = `${baseURL}videos?api_key=${apiKEY}`;

    const fetchData = () => axios
        .get(url)
        .then((resp) => setSelectedVideo(resp.data));

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    const [selectedVideo, setSelectedVideo] = useState(null);
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense then. Thanks for the detailed answer! Been struggling on this for quite some time haha. This made me realise that I could also cut down the code a little bit to this here... which ends up doing the same.

```
    const [selectedVideo, setSelectedVideo] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url).then((resp) => {
            setSelectedVideo(resp.data);
        });
    }, []);
```

Comment: @timohuennebeck Yes, you also can do that, if you don't need to use `fetchData` function in another place in the component.